# undefined method `propfind' for ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, actiondispatch

I am trying to implement `git push` on my rails app and it sends PROPFIND request which rails doesn't seem to validate. When I try:

git push http://localhost:3000/satellite/.git

it gives me:

> Started PROPFIND "/satellite/.git/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-08
>   19:20:38 +0530
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PROPFIND]
>   "/satellite/.git")

however `git clone http://localhost:3000/satellite/.git` works just fine. (ie repo exists there.)

If I try to add propfind to my routes.rb file it gives me:

> undefined method `propfind' for ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper

I found this: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5895-allow-mounting-of-rack-apps-that-deal-with-http-extensions

I think after that patch they allowed PROPFIND in ActionDispatch, and in [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-authorization) they have mentioned propfind as RFC3253 constant.Is there any way I can enable PROPFIND?

Comment: Not a direct solution for you, but it appears that someone else was having this issue with Rails `~ 3.1` and made a gem you might want to look at https://github.com/wvk/railsdav

Comment: thanks @JonathanBender. I was using dumb http protocol, hence during push it was falling back to webdav and sending a profind request. I switched to smart http with https://github.com/gitlabhq/grack and push now sends post request. However, I still don't understand why would rails not validate a propfind request, because my app was not webdav app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you have to add `PROPFIND` requests to your routes via a generic matcher, ([see this test](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/21f7bcbaa7709ed072bb2e1273d25c09eeaa26d9/actionpack/test/dispatch/routing_test.rb#L3853-L3887)), so the following should work for you:

```
resources :git_repos do
  member do
    match '.git' => :your_route, :via => :propfind
  end
end
```

Comment: Not that I need it, as smart http is definitely better than webdav, however it works and I don't get undefined method anymore. RFC2616 has get and post method and RFC2518 has propfind, if normal conventional way works for RFC2616 then why shouldn't it work for RFC2518?

Comment: My guess is that in an effort to encourage people to conform to the "Rails way," those convenience methods only exist for RFC2616, but they "support" all the other RFCs through the `via` option *if you really want to* (emphasis mine).